# Minor version upgrade of RDS and impact on followers

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Last time I performed a major `postgresql` RDS version upgrade, the followers were really messed.

I am about to perform a minor version upgrade (something like `12.5` --> `12.6`) and i cannot find any relevant documentation about if and what type of impact this may have on the followers.

Any directions towards any relevant docs?

Comment: What do you mean by followers? Read replicas?

Comment: yes, I mean read-replicas

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS documentation:

> There are two kinds of upgrades: major version upgrades and minor version upgrades. In general, a major engine version upgrade can introduce changes that are not compatible with existing applications. In contrast, **a minor version upgrade includes only changes that are backward-compatible with existing applications.**

[Source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html)

I can also mention that I've been running a few RDS PostgreSQL clusters in production, with perhaps all the possible flavors, Aurora RDS with PostgreSQL provisined, Aurora RDS serverless, RDS PostgreSQL and never had an issue when doing a minor upgrade either with master, replicas or clients, we even have the automatic minor version upgrade enabled.